# My button doesn't work inside a method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, object, listbox

I have a xaml page with a reaction form. I load this reaction dynamicly in a listbox but the button that I use on this reaction doesn't work. I load the reactions as objects in the listbox.

This is the reaction

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border Background="DarkGray" CornerRadius="10" Width="400">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="400" Background="DarkGray" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbDateCreated" Text="tbDateCreated" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="15" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Width="152" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Margin="190,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbTimeCreated" Text="tbTimeCreated" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="15" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Width="152" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Margin="270,0,-70,0" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbAuthor" Text="tbAuthor" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="15" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="158" Foreground="White" />
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tbContent" Text="tbContent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,20,0" Foreground="White" />
            <Line Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" Margin="10,20,10,0" />
            <Border Background="Gray" Width="90" Height="30" Margin="-290,10,0,0" CornerRadius="10">
            <Button x:Name="reageer" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Gray" Margin="-5,-12,0,0" Height="60" Width="100" FontSize="12" Click="Button_Click" Tap="reageer_Tap"  Content="Reageer" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And this is the code to load the reaction with data.

```
    public string DateCreated { get { return tbDateCreated.Text; } set { tbDateCreated.Text = value; } }
    public string TimeCreated { get { return tbTimeCreated.Text; } set { tbTimeCreated.Text = value; } }
    public string Author { get { return tbAuthor.Text; } set { tbAuthor.Text = value; } }
    public string TextContent { get { return tbContent.Text; } set { tbContent.Text = value; } }
```

In the next page I load this reaction.

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="lbComments" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
```

How can I use the button in my reaction to work on the page where the listbox is?

Comment: Why do you set IsHitTestVisible="False" ? is it needed? It can cause buttons not to act as expected

Comment: I am so ashamed right now it worked :S thx. I just it for something else